# Trying to download organization data to an external drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, download, cloud

I am trying to backup all of our Google Cloud data to an external storage device.

There is a lot of data so I am attempting to download the entire bucket at once and am using the following command to do so, but it halts saying that there isn't enough storage on the device to complete the transfer.

```
gsutil -m cp -r \
  "bucket name" \
  .
```

What do I need to add to this command to download this information to my local D: drive? I have searched through the available docs and have not been able to find the answer.

I used the `gsutil` command that GCP provided for me automatically, but it seems to be trying to copy the files to a destination without enough storage to hold the needed data.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you are running the command from the Cloud Shell and not in a local terminal or Windows Command Line. If you inspect the Cloud Shell's file system/structure, it resembles more that of a Unix environment in which you can specify the destination like such instead: `~/bucketfiles/`. Even a simple `gsutil -m cp -R gs://bucket-name.appspot.com ./` will work since Cloud Shell can identify the `./` directory which is the current directory.

A workaround to this is to perform the command on your Windows Command Line. You would have to [install Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#windows) beforehand.

Alternatively, this can also be done in Cloud Shell, albeit with an extra step:

Download the bucket objects by running g`sutil -m cp -R gs://bucket-name ~/` which will download it into the home directory in Cloud Shell
Transfer the files downloaded in the `~/` (home) directory from Cloud Shell to the local machine either through the [User Interface](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/uploading-and-downloading-files) or by running [gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/cloud-shell/scp).